# Bad function arity and warning: function hello_world/0 is unused

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I just started learning Erlang so I coded this as `new.erl`:

```
-module(new).
-export([hello_world]/0).
 hello_world()->io:fwrite("Hello\n").
```

So the function name is `hello_world` and it holds `Hello` as string.

But whenever I want to run this, I get this result:

```
new.erl:2: bad function arity
new.erl:3: Warning: function hello_world/0 is unused
error
```

So how to solve this problem, what's going wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
 -export( [ hello_world ]/0 )
```

It should be:

```
 -export( [ hello_world/0 ] ).
```

`export` requires a list, where each element in the list is the function name followed by a slash followed by the arity of the function.  A list does not have an arity, which is what you wrote.

Note that when you are just writing test code, it is easier to use:

```
-compile(export_all).
```

which will export all functions defined in your module.